# Updating a file with sed

Tags: unix, sed

I am trying to find and replace a couple of words in a file and try to execute that file as a .sql file

```
sed -e "s/wordToFind1/UnixFile/g" Check.sql;
sed -e "s/wordToFind2/WordToReplace2/g" Check.sql;
```

In the above, I am trying to find wordToFind1 and replace it with a UnixFile : /usr/bin/try.txt
and then, trying to find wordToFind2 and replace it with another word : tablename

**Before** sed - Check.sql :

```
servermonitor on
spool wordToFind1
select * from wordToFind2
```

**After** sed - Check.sql :

```
servermonitor on
spool /usr/bin/try.txt
select * from tablename
```

Once the above changes are done, I am trying to execute the sql file. Please help!!!

Comment: You don't execute an sql file, you just feed it to your database's command line tools...

Comment: I dont want to put the plsql contents in the unix script, I wanted it to be in a seperate file. Can you pls give me a sample.

Comment: @nhahtdh : question is, I am trying to find a word and replace it with a unix path/file using sed. Once done, execute that .sql file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant get something in sed. So i have used awk.
Pass the Replace1 and Replace2 as argument to the shell script which will create the ip.sql with proper values.

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -v R1=$1 -v R2=$2 '{gsub("wordToFind1",R1);gsub("wordToFind2",R2);print}' ip.sql > t.sql;
mv t.sql ip.sql;
```

Comment: is it working with a unix filepath as word to replace.. its not working for me :(

Comment: I tried with these 2 options ./h4.sh /usr/bin/try.txt tablename and it works fine

Answer (score 6):

You have some problems to solve here.

## Using slashes (`/`) inside `s///`

First, you want to replace `wordToFind1` with `/usr/bin/try.txt`. It will not work with the `s///` command at first, because the replacing string contains `/`. It would to a very weird command!

```
sed -e 's/wordToFind1//usr/bin/try.txt/' Check.sql
```

Sed will think that the command is `s/wordToFind1//` with some flags (such as `u`) and other commands following, but it makes no sense and it will generate an error. A solution is to escape each `/` from `/usr/bin/try.txt` with `\`:

```
$ sed -e 's/wordToFind1/\/usr\/bin\/try.txt/' Check.sql
servermonitor on
spool /usr/bin/try.txt
select * from wordToFind2
```

This is clumsy, however. When you have a lot of `/` in your replacing string (or even in the replaced string), a better solution IMHO is to use another character as the delimiters of `s///`.  Not everybody knows it is possible, but one can use any other char instead of `/` as the delimiter of `s///`. In this case, you can use as much `/` as you want inside your expressions without needing of escaping them. In the example below, I am using `#` instead of `/`, so the slashes from `/usr/bin/try.txt` cause no trouble:

```
$ sed -e 's#wordToFind1#/usr/bin/try.txt#' Check.sql
servermonitor on
spool /usr/bin/try.txt
select * from wordToFind2
```

## Using more than one `s///` command

Solved that, you should replace `wordToFind2` too. This is easy: just pass another `-e` command in the same sed invocation:

```
$ sed -e 's#wordToFind1#/usr/bin/try.txt#' -e 's/wordToFind2/tablename/' Check.sql
servermonitor on
spool /usr/bin/try.txt
select * from tablename
```

(Another option is to add more than one option in one string only, separarated by semicolons:

```
$ sed -e 's#wordToFind1#/usr/bin/try.txt#;s/wordToFind2/tablename/' Check.sql
servermonitor on
spool /usr/bin/try.txt
select * from tablename
```

I find it very useful sometimes, with bigger sed scripts, but it is less readable as well).

## Updating the input file with `-i`

Now, you need to update the `Check.sql` file. This is easy as well: just pass the `-i` flag to sed. This flag makes sed update the original file. Also, this flag can receive a parameter, that is an extension to be added to a backup file with the original content. In this case, I will use the `.bkp` extension. See the results:

```
$ sed -i.bkp -e 's#wordToFind1#/usr/bin/try.txt#' -e 's/wordToFind2/tablename/' Check.sql
$ cat Check.sql
servermonitor on
spool /usr/bin/try.txt
select * from tablename
```

Now, `Check.sql` changed. Also, there is a `Check.sql.bkp` with the old content:

```
$ cat Check.sql.bkp 
servermonitor on
spool wordToFind1
select * from wordToFind2
```

This may be helpful if something goes wrong.

Comment: Problem is the replace string should be dynamic